# Java callback using ExecutorService threadsafe aggregate total

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

In my main method I declare 30 runnable workers and then pass each one a number of tasks they need to complete. I would like it reported in realtime and as an aggregate and to not block the execution of the workers. The realtime reporting should just be a println to the console with some statistics

Pseudocode:

1. Create thread pool of 30 workers.
2. Create x number of jobs for each worker.
3. Start timer to track performance and start execution of each worker.
4. Every time a worker completes a task, it should callback to a method in main that will increment an int that keeps track of how many have been completed. This must be thread safe
5. Every 5 seconds, print out to the screen how many jobs have been completed until all jobs are completed.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why submit a batch of jobs to each worker? Why not just submit the jobs and let the ExecutorService handle dispatch, since this is what an ExecutorService does to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic is sound, just use AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet() for counting and you are good to go.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html